# Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to set theme of my app according to what the user chooses. It can be dark theme or light theme.

I have created viewModel as:

```
class ThemeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val _darkMode = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
    val darkMode : LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _darkMode


    fun setDarkMode(isDarkMode:Boolean){
        _darkMode.value = isDarkMode
    }

    fun getDarkMode():Boolean = _darkMode.value!!

}
```

I have created my theme as :

```
@Composable
fun VoodleeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors,
        content = content
    )
```

}

I used setContent as :

```
setContent {
  MyApp {
    val doDark: Boolean by 
    themeViewModel.darkMode.observeAsState(Boolean) //this line gives error

    VoodleeTheme(darkTheme = doDark) {
    ProgressNavigation(themeViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help m fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
 val doDark: State<Boolean> = themeViewModel.darkMode.observeAsState(initial = false)
```

In place of:

```
val doDark: Boolean by themeViewModel.darkMode.observeAsState(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add,

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

This is an extension function for `MutableState<T>` that implements the requirements to use `by` in a `val`.

Comment: I have already imported it. But it shows that this import is unused.

Comment: If this fixes the compiler error then the IDE is wrong to report that this import is unused.